# Will modulus give me $n - 1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Say I divide a number by 6, will a number modulus by 6 always be between 0-5? If so, will a number modulus any number (N) , the result should be between $0$ and $ N - 1$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the [Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) : For any $a, n \in \mathbb{Z}, n\neq 0$, there exist $q,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$
a = qn + r, 0 \leq r < |n|
$$
and by definition, $a\equiv r\pmod{n}$

Comment: No, this is Euclidean division, as you link correctly says. The [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) is more complicated and serves for computing $\gcd$s, though it is based on Euclidean division.

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether you regard modulus as a function or as an equivalence relation.

It is often useful to identify numbers which are equivalent to "$-1 \mod p$".

It also depends on what you mean by "number": what would you say "$11.4 \mod 6$" was?

If you say "$61 \equiv 79 \mod 6$" then I would say the answer was no.

But if you would say "`mod(61,6) = 1 = mod(79,6)`" (rather like the Excel function) then I would say the answer was yes.

Comment: Interesting: I would say that $61\equiv79\bmod 6$ is true! Maybe I'm misunderstanding your sentence.

Comment: So would I since their difference is a multiple of $6$, which suggests that  "the result" need not be between $0$ and $N-1$

Comment: I see - I wasn't clear on what question you were answering with "no".

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that by "number", you mean an integer, although it doesn't matter for everything I say.

The answer to your question depends a little on your point of view. I would say that $x\bmod n$ is usually best interpreted as the set of numbers $[x]_n=\{x+kn:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. However, there is a unique element of this set that lies between $0$ and $n-1$, so we could also use this.

For example, if $x=15$ and $n=6$, then $[15]_6=\{\dotsc,-9,-3,3,9,15,21,\dotsc,\}$, and the unique element between $0$ and $5$ is $3$.

One key point is that if you want to do a calculation involving only addition and multiplication, but you only care about the answer modulo $n$, you can replace any of the numbers $x$ in your calculation by any element of $[x]_n$, without changing the answer modulo $n$.

For example, modulo $6$:

$$15\times 3\equiv 3\times 3\equiv 9\equiv 3$$

Note how every time I get to a "$\equiv$", I either do some arithmetic, or replace one number from the set $[15]_6$ with a different one.